# SQL Server 2014, trigger : how to iterate over deleted rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

ATTENTION! Using trigger is necessary for me! The only way needed for me to perform following task - is to use trigger!

The question is - I need a trigger, which would be called on rowS deletion in a certain table. The thing trigger must do - iterate over every deleted
row, and perform some code - depending on current iterated row values.

for example, I made this trigger, which works when I delete one row
by command

```
DELETE FROM books WHERE id=5
```

the trigger is here:

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER onBookDelete ON books
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
DECLARE @book_id int
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT id FROM deleted
    SET @book_id = (SELECT id FROM deleted)
    PRINT @book_id
    BEGIN 
         DELETE FROM "books-topics" WHERE book_id=@book_id
         DELETE FROM "books-genres" WHERE book_id=@book_id
         DELETE FROM books WHERE id=@book_id
    END
END;
```

So, what I want to achieve - is to create trigger with same task, 
but it must work when I delete many rows at one time, for example

```
 DELETE FROM books WHERE id=5 OR id=3 OR id=8
```

by same task I mean, for example, calling the following code on each deleted row

```
DELETE FROM "books-topics" WHERE id=DELETEDROW.book_id
DELETE FROM "books-genres" WHERE id=DELETEDROW.book_id 
DELETE FROM books WHERE id=DELETEDROW.book_id
```

Comment: This has [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Written all over it. Please edit your question to describ the problem you try to solve instead of the solution you try to use.

Comment: Why not just declare foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: If you want to do something after deleting a row, use an `AFTER` trigger. You don't need a trigger at all to cascade deletes though.

Comment: You don't need to process each row individually. Remove the `FOR EACH DELETED ROW` and use a join in the DELETE statements. Once you do that, you'll realize you can execute such statements in a single batch without resorting to triggers

Comment: Just rememberd I've answerd a question like this yesterday....

Comment: The answer I gave to the duplicate question should work just fine for you also. Best to use foreign keys with on delete cascade as Damien suggested.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I edited my question. On delete cascade is a cool thing, but not the one I can do now. It's a task from my teacher - to do perform this task using trigger. I surfed the net - didn't find how to iterate over deleted rows :(

Comment: The key thing here, and what's shown in Zohar's answer is that you *don't* iterate. You should try, in general in SQL, to write *set-based* logic. You don't want to run 5 `DELETE`s in a child table to delete the rows relating to 5 rows deleted in the parent - you want to run *1* `DELETE` that affects the entire set of affected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher should have thought about a better example for an instead of delete trigger. This problem is what on delete cascade is there for in the first place.

However, since your assignment is to use a trigger, I would suggest something like this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER onBookDelete ON books
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRASACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE bt
        FROM "books-topics" bt
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON bt.book_id= d.book_id

        DELETE bg
        FROM "books-genres" bg
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON bg.book_id= d.book_id

        DELETE b
        FROM books b
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON b.book_id= d.book_id

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END;
```

Comment: oh. I see. Didn't think of using transactions here. Thank You much!  this helped